# Get data back with extension .java

Tags: java, eclipse, data-recovery, file-recovery

I delete my java program from java project in eclipse. The extension was .java and I don't know how to get back? I try (getdataback for NTFS) but I didn't get back my *.java file. Some solution?

Comment: don't you use any version controll system?

Comment: Do you have the `.class` files? (the compiled `.java` files)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse, it has the ability to [restore deleted files](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/eclipse/how-to-restore-deleted-files-in-eclipse.html). Right Click on your project, and then choose **Restore from Local History...** option.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on your project and select "Restore from Local History", it might still be there.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have the `.class` files, or can get them back with a recovery tool, you can use a decompiler to try and convert (decompile) them back to `.java` source files.

More info on decompilers for Java can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353/is-jad-the-best-java-decompiler

If you're looking for help on how to get deleted data back, [Superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) would be a more suitable place to ask your question.

And next time, back up your files more often, or better, use a source control system like GIT or SVN (and back that up too, of courtse!).